# Significado de "entonar" en un contexto culinario

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado

Leo en [un artículo](https://m.directoalpaladar.com/directo-al-paladar/cinco-caldos-para-entonar-el-picoteo-del-finde-que-presenta-gelido) de un blog lo siguiente:

> Cinco caldos para entonar el picoteo del finde

El título del artículo me ha dejado un poco extrañado. ¿Qué quiere decir "entonar el picoteo"? Según las acepciones de *[entonar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Finzl4f)*, puede ser (resumiendo un poco):

- Cantar ajustándose al tono.
- Fortalecer o vigorizar el organismo.
- Armonizar colores.
- Beber alcohol de forma moderada.
- Envanecerse, engreírse.

De estos significados los que más me cuadran son el segundo y el tercero. Pero el segundo se usa como pronominal, para fortalecerse uno (la definición habla del organismo y no de otra cosa). Y el tercero se usa en pintura, aunque entiendo que podría referirse a darle más color al picoteo.

El caso es que no me queda demasiado claro. En el artículo no lo aclaran, simplemente repiten esta expresión varias veces. ¿Cómo se entiende por tanto este titular?

Comment: *Creo* que se usa en el sentido de que el caldo, siendo primer plato, establece un sabor que va afectando el gusto, o simplemente, estableciendo el *tono* (en el sentido de *ambiente/tema*) de la comida.  De esta forma podría ser algo como en las acepciones 2, 4 o 6.

Comment: Para los chilenos "entonado" es "encendido", con ganas de empezar a pasarlo bien. Por supuesto, es un derivado de la 4a acepción. Siento que calza bien "...para _encender_ el picoteo...", pero mirando los ingredientes de las recetas del blog se nota que no tiene nada que ver con Chile.

Answer (score 1):

Entonar también se puede utilizar para referirse a que algo da tono. *Tono* según el contexto puede referirse a *color* entre otras cosas, pero en un contexto culinario hace referencia a darle aroma, color, sabor, "vigorizar o realzar cualidades", si se quiere, también en relación al segundo significado que comentaste. Todo eso simboliza esta expresión.

Answer (score 0):

Considero que el mejor uso para "entonar" en este contexto es el segundo significado. Quiere decir "fortalecer", "acentuar"

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, en el contexto culinario *entonar(se)* está relacionado con poner(se) *a tono.*

[RAE: "a tono"](http://dle.rae.es/?w=a%20tono)

> **a tono**
>
> 1. loc. adv. En armonía. Se vistió a tono con la ocasión. U. t. c. loc. adj. Se llevan los vestidos estampados con bolso y zapatos a
>      tono.
> 2. loc. adj. **En buen estado, o en el estado deseable**. Necesitas entrenarte más para ponerte a tono.

Comment: Si lees el artículo verás que la palabra "caldo" se usa literalmente: se refiere a sopas diversas con las que complementar la comida.

Comment: Gracias Carlos, era un presuposición. Elimino entonces esa referencia de mi respuesta.